# Bootstrap: using typeahead with grid, is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with a grid for a form. The form has is in grid but the grid changes after selecting a typeahead. Is this a bug?

http://jsfiddle.net/wcQKP/ (must resize html section to be wide to see the grid)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
... 

$('#inputEmail').typeahead({
...
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of this:

```
.controls-row [class*="span"]+[class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

This property will be applied only if the element with the class containing the word `span` is immediately preceded by another element containing this same word and being inside an object with the `controls-row` class.
(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

This works when you load the page:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" class="span3">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Password" class="span2">
</div>
```

But as soon as you trigger typeahead, a new HTML element is added:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" class="span3">
  <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" style="top: 90px; left: 210px; display: none;">
    <li data-value="gmail.com" class="active"><a href="#">gmail.com</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Password" class="span2">
 </div>
</div>
```

You could fix this by adding in your css something like:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #inputPassword {
      margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

See for the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wcQKP/2/

*Note: I changed the id for the password input from `inputEmail` to `inputPassword`*

Comment: `            @media (min-width: 768px) {#password {margin-left: 20px}}
            @media (min-width: 1200px) {#password {margin-left: 30px}}
`

Comment: HERE IS THE END-ALL ANSWER:            ` @media (min-width: 768px) {
              .controls-row *+[class*="span"]{
                  margin-left: 20px
              }
            } 
            @media (min-width: 1200px) {
              .controls-row *+[class*="span"] {
                  margin-left: 30px
              }
            }
`